# Android CellSignalStrength (when network type is UMTS)

Tags: android

Can any body know how to get CellSignalStrength i.e getDbm() When Network type is UMTS. When the network type is LTE or GSM we can use classes like http://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/CellSignalStrengthLte.html

But dnt know how to get UMTS SignalStrength and is there any class provided by android for this? please help me out

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Answer to my Question is You should use CDMA 
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/CellSignalStrengthCdma.html

Because UMTS is type of CDMA so I think it should work.

The Code I am using for GSM,LTE,UMTS is this and its working fine for me.

```
  public void onSignalStrengthsChanged(SignalStrength signalStrength) {
            super.onSignalStrengthsChanged(signalStrength);

                 CellSignalStrengthLte1 a1=new CellSignalStrengthLte1();
                a1.initialize(signalStrength, 1);
                MyService.signal=a1.getDbm();

                if(MyService.signal>0){
                    CellSignalStrengthGsm1 a3=new CellSignalStrengthGsm1();
                a3.initialize(signalStrength.getGsmSignalStrength(), 1);
                MyService.signal=a3.getDbm();

                    }

                if(MyService.signal>0)
                {
                    CellSignalStrengthCdma1 a2=new CellSignalStrengthCdma1();
                    a2.initialize(signalStrength.getCdmaDbm(),signalStrength.getCdmaEcio(),signalStrength.getEvdoDbm(), signalStrength.getEvdoEcio(),signalStrength.getEvdoSnr());
                    MyService.signal=a2.getDbm();


                }



        }
```